# Google Doc style comments? Direct a Comment to a particular user

Tags: trello, comments

One of the features I absolutely LOVE in Google Docs is **Comment directed at a user's email**.

Is there a way to do something like that in Trello?

Use Case:
I'm working on a task with our UX designer and he makes a suggestion. I want to quickly find out if the Subject Matter Expert agrees or as any comments.

I guess I could add him to the Card, but how will he *know he's now got a "task*? (question to answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I found the answer just as I finished my question. But wanted to post it here for posterity.*

In the **Comment** blank (under Activity), **type @**  and then the user **name**. Works just like Google Docs.  Sweet!